# Decode nsData to String Array

Tags: swift

I want to decode my nsData to a String Array. I have this code right now:

```
func nsDataToStringArray(data: NSData) -> [String] {
            var decodedStrings = [String]()

            var stringTerminatorPositions = [Int]()

            var currentPosition = 0
            data.enumerateBytes() {
                buffer, range, stop in

                let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buffer)
                for i in 0 ..< range.length {
                    if bytes[i] == 0 {
                        stringTerminatorPositions.append(currentPosition)
                    }

                    currentPosition += 1
                }
            }

            var stringStartPosition = 0
            for stringTerminatorPosition in stringTerminatorPositions {
                let encodedString = data.subdata(with: NSMakeRange(stringStartPosition, stringTerminatorPosition - stringStartPosition))
                let decodedString =  NSString(data: encodedString, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
                decodedStrings.append(decodedString)
                stringStartPosition = stringTerminatorPosition + 1
            }

            return decodedStrings
        }
```

But I get an error on this line: let bytes = `UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buffer)`

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer' with an
>   argument list of type '(UnsafeRawPointer)'

Do I need to convert the buffer to a UnsafePointer? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buffer` in the `enumerateBytes()` closure is a `UnsafeRawPointer`
and you have to "rebind" it to an `UInt8` pointer in Swift 3:

```
// let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buffer)
let bytes = buffer.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
```

But why so complicated? You can achieve the same result with

```
func nsDataToStringArray(nsData: NSData) -> [String] {
    let data = nsData as Data
    return data.split(separator: 0).flatMap { String(bytes: $0, encoding: .utf8) }
}
```

How does this work?

- `Data` is a `Sequence` of `UInt8`, therefore
- `split(separator: 0)` can be called on it, returning an array of
  "data slices" (which are views into the source data, not copies).
- Each "data slice" is again a `Sequence` of `UInt8`, from which a 
  `String` can be created with `String(bytes: $0, encoding: .utf8)`.
  This is a failable initializer (because the data may be invalid UTF-8).
- `flatMap { ... }` returns an array with all non-nil results,
  i.e. an array with all strings which could be created from 
  valid UTF-8 code sequences between zero bytes.

Comment: In Swift 3 I'd prefer the signature `func stringArray(from nsData: NSData)` ;-)

Comment: @vadian: Indeed! Or `func stringArray(from data: Data)`, if possible. – I kept the name so that OP can directly test it with his/her code.

Comment: We don't need to talk about misusing obsolete `NS...` Foundation classes in Swift 3...